# Do I need to download Google drive if I'm only using Google docs (apps)?

Tags: google-drive

I've been using Google docs for years. Nothing needed on my computer.  Do I need to download Google drive on my Mac to continue use Google docs spreadsheets etc?

Also on one of our computers (accounts) ALL our files are gone.  Empty, like starting over.

Comment: Update: My wife said she pushed something that she didn't read. There were about 80 files in her google account. Now all gone. Is there a simple button pushed that would delete this? There is nothing in the trash. This is very fishy.

Comment: If you have a Business Account, then you have around the clock support. You don't need to install the google drive, to keep on using the things you used too. Good luck in trying to salvage your documents...

Comment: You have asked two questions here. The first has an answer, please move the second into it's own question.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to download Drive for the computer if all you want to do is edit documents online. Drive for the computer is meant to sync all of your non-Google Docs related files to you Drive account, and it also helps to allow you to edit files on your computer while you're offline (offline editing)

As far as the one account that has lost all of its documents is concerned, can you provide more context? Is the user signed in? Do you have access to the associated Gmail account? What are you seeing when you try to view your docs?